# prolog constraint programming and forall/2

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm using SWI 7.2.3 and have the following program :

```
?-use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- dynamic size/2,wall/2.

in_board(X,Y):-X #> 0,Y #> 0,size(N,M),X #=< N,Y #=< M.

wall_exists_line(X,Y,W) :- wall(X,Z),(Y #=< Z,W #=< Y;Y#=< W,Z#=< Y).

wall_not_exists_line(X,Y,W) :- not(wall_exists_line(X,Y,W)).

same_line(X,Y,Z,W):- X #= Z,in_board(Z,W),in_board(X,Y),wall_not_exists_line(X,Y,W).
```

I'm using constraint programming here because I want `in_board` to work even when both `X` and `Y` are not instantiated(yes I know it could be implemented other ways but I found this to be easier).

As you can see `size,wall` are dynamic and both essentially takes integers.

My problem is if I assert `size(4,4)` and `wall(2,2)` and query `same_line(X,1,Y,3)` it returns false when it should return `X = Y, X in 1\/3..4`(or alike).

I know that `not(something(X))` means "no X exists where something is true", I wanted "there exists X where something(X) is not true"(by something I actually mean `wall_exists_line`).

I tried using `forall` but forall doesn't work good with constraints as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946662/prolog-foreach-or-forall-for-constraint-solving) question.

A solution for my particular problem can be found But I'd prefer a general answer, that is how to do for constraints what `forall` would do normally ?.

### Big Goal

The program above is just a subset of a prolog program which is supposed to solve akari game(also called light-up, see [game](http://www.puzzle-light-up.com/)), the predicate `same_line` is needed to determine which cells are lighten up by some light.

`size(N,M)` means our board has `N` rows and `M` columns, `wall(X,Y)` means the cell `(X,Y)` is a wall.

### Edit

I didn't have `wall_not_exists_line` before, I put `not(wall_exists_line)` directly in `same_line`, I thought introducing separate predicate would solve it but it didn't.

I thought of changing `wall_exists_line` into the negation of it, the negation of `q and p` is `not(q) or not(p)` so `wall_exists_line` would change to this:

```
wall_not_exists_line(X,Y,W) :- not(wall(X,Z));(not(Y #=<Z);not(W #=<Y)),(not(Y#=<W);not(Z#=<Y)).
```

Unfortunately `not(wall(X,Z))` means "No X or Z exists for which wall(X,Z) is true", I don't want this and as `wall` is dynamic I can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

`not(wall_exists_line(X,Y,W))` would check every value of `X` and `Y` and `W` if they don't have a fixed value.

`in_board(X,Y)` constraint both `X` and `Y` in intervals but not a fixed value so `not` would try every value in the interval.

The solution is to have the variables `X,Y,W` instantiated before entering `not`, this is done by changing `in_board` to this :

```
in_board(X,Y):-size(N,M),between(0,N,X),between(0,M,Y).
```

This way `between` will instantiate `X` and `Y` and fortunately `between` gives all the values in the interval.

The main difference between clpfd and just `between` is that clpfd returns domain while `between` - if the third argument isn't instantiated - returns every value between two values.

Comment: When working with CLP(FD) constraints, you no longer need `between/3`: Use the enumeration predicates `indomain/1`, `label/1` or `labeling/2` to obtain ground solutions when you need them. Even more elegant would be to **generalize** your remaining predicates to also work with arbitrary *variables*, not just ground integers!

Comment: I tried `indomain` , `label` ,etc , I didn't know how to use them.  
Anyway I didn't understand your last statement, what do you mean by "ground integers" ?

Comment: If `X` is sufficiently constrained, for example by `X in 0..N`, you can simply state `indomain(X)` to obtain fitting integers for `X`. By "ground integers" I mean terms like 1, 7, 10 etc. Note that if we have a constraint `X in 0..5`, then `X` is conceptually also definitely an *integer*, but it is not yet instantiated to a ground term.